# How can I make a bootstrap navbar/tab section scrollable horizontally?

Tags: css, twig

I have a tab section made with `bootstrap navbar`, like this:

```
<nav ng-controller="Controller">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#progress" data-toggle="tab">Progress</a>
      {% include 'coachmark.html.twig' with { 'key': 'overview.progress', 'arrow': 'left' } %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#team" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setAllCommentsAsRead()">
        <span ng-class="{ 'icon-notification': commentNotification }">Team</span>
      </a>
      {% include 'coachmark.html.twig' with { 'key': 'overview.progress', 'arrow': 'left' } %}
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tests" data-toggle="tab">Tests</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="announcements.length > 0">
      <a href="#announcements" data-toggle="tab" ng-click="setAllAnnouncementsAsRead()">
        <span ng-class="{ 'icon-notification': announcementNotification }">Announcements</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

When the screen gets too small (mobile/tablet size), the last `<li>`, that has a `float: left`, goes underneath the first one, to a second row.

I would like to make it scrollable horizontally, in order to keep all the elements in the same row.

I've been messing around with `overflow`, `white-space`, `display` (etc) classes but I just make either the last tab mostly disappear with no chance of horizontal scroll or just create a huge empty gap on the right side of the page to make space to the last tab.

[Here's a Pen](https://codepen.io/Ryuuks/pen/jxzGBM?editors=1100) for better visualization of the issue.

EDIT: Removed the `includes` from the Pen just to make it easier on the eye, they are needed.

Comment: which browser are you testing in? It seems to work fine in chrome. When I resize it to small, scrollbar is being shown  overflow:auto works.

Comment: @yer Maybe I wasn't very clear: I want to replicate the behavior of the second example of the Pen, using the same `<ul> <li>` structure of the first, which is the one I'm using in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its wrapping cause its a flex item and has `flex-wrap:wrap` on it. I've changed it for you and added a few other properties for the scrollbars to appear.

Code:

```
.nav-tabs {
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y:hidden;
 }
```

[**Example**](https://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/erMexa?editors=1100)

Comment: That is exactly what i wanted, however I can't replicate your example for some reason. Mine just looks like if you remove `flex-wrap: nowrap;` of your example

Comment: There might be a property overwriting your `nowrap` which has higher specificity. Try adding !important after it see if it works.

Comment: No luck even with `!important`. My first reaction is to think it must be other classes property as well, but I've been messing with all of them, child and parent and can't figure it out. I guess I'll just keep digging.
Thank you for the help!